# How do I transfer photo/video from Ipad2 to Windows XP computer? What driver when asks for new hardware found? (Don't have disk)

Tags: ipad, photos, data-transfer, software, windows

I have an ipad2 and windows XP service pack 3.
When put USB to Windows XP it recognizes IPad2 and I can hit "Trust this computer' on Ipad2.  However, the windows XP computer then says "new hardware found" insert installation disk if have one.

I don't have it.
The computer's new hardware wizard can then choose best to install the software (recommended)... It chooses "Digital Still Camera".  If I click "Next", it then says warning this has not passed windows logo testing to verify its' compatibility with XP and may lead to destabilization. So, if I cancel then the hardware (IPad2) is not recognized. Please help!

I know I need to get the proper software/driver installed on the Windows XP computer so it will show the IPad 2 in my camera & scanner area.  Once I do that, I need to know the next steps to transfer the photos on IPad2 also. THX!
PS- I do have up to date iTunes version on XP computer.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is likely to be that you in fact **don't** have the latest iTunes, because it will not run on Windows XP.

The oldest supported MS OS is Windows 7. See http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/